# R square and R square adjusted

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

As $R^2$ increases, $R^2_{adj}$ increases too.

Is that statement true?

Comment: Is that probably a [tag:self-study] question? Consider tagging it as such. Regarding the question, open up any econometrics textbook, and you will find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $R_{\text{adj}}^2 = 1-(1-R^2){n-1 \over n-p-1}$

So, if you fix $n$ and $p$, but move your data points about to increase $R^2$, then yes, adjusted $R^2$ must increase.